# Getting last child of each parent with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Is there an easy way to select last li of each of these lists with jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried those two methods but both of them return only one element.

```
$("ul li").last()
$("ul li:last")
```

I would use the CSS :last-child pseudo-class but since it was introduced in CSS3 and IE8 doesn't support it, I cannot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would use the CSS :last-child pseudo-class but since it was introduced in CSS3 and IE8 doesn't support it, I cannot

You can since you're using jQuery to select your elements, because jQuery implements it itself so that browsers that don't support it natively in CSS can still use it:

```
$("ul li:last-child")
```

Comment: I didn't expect it was that simple, thanks a lot for solution and explanation

Answer (score 5):

The [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector is what you need. Same logic as the CSS3 `:last-child` selector, but you can freely use it in jQuery as jQuery will provide it for you even if the browser's CSS engine does not understand it.

```
$("ul li:last-child")
```

From the documentation:

> While `:last` matches only a single element, `:last-child` can match more
>   than one: one for each parent.

[Nice little demo attached](http://jsfiddle.net/pPsMh/)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      $('ul li:last-child').css("color","red");
                  });
```

Check This Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ganeshprabhu1994/surve/2/